# Finding a specific member of an ascending list of whole number powers sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

I've been tasked with writing a program to find a $a_k$ member of a sequence:

$
a_0=4=2^2, a_1=8=2^3, a_2=9=3^2, a_3=16=4^2=2^4, a_4=25=5^2, a_5=27=3^3, a_6=32=2^5
$

and so on. I've coded up a brute-force solution, which takes advantage of $m^n$s logarithmic contours for $m>2$ and $n>2$:

[image: m^n plot][image]

The checking for each following member goes right-to-left through the table below, checking max $m$ for every $n$ and filtering out the repeated values (i.e. $64=8^2=4^3=2^6$). However, the method is too slow for me and I was wondering if there was a way to get to that $a_k$ element ($1<=k<=10^6$) by expressing this sequence as a formula? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You might want to edit $a_2 = 9 = 3^2 $ instead of $32$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems difficult, see [the information provided in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001597). However, brute force approaches give some results.

One may for instance **list all numbers satisfying your conditions, until a given maximal value, and then sort them**. The maximal value must be large enough to reach $k$ values (it seems from experiments and OEIS that it should be close tp $k^2$).

The following Python code makes the job, if I am correct:

```
sqrt_max_val = 10**6
max_val = sqrt_max_val**2
values = set()

for i in range(2,sqrt_max_val):
        val = i*i
        while val<max_val:
                values.add(val)
                val *= i

print("nb values: "+str(len(values)))
for x in sorted(values):
        print(x)
```

Notice that it uses a `set` to avoid duplicates, and that a full answer would have to find `sqrt_max_val` automatically (by increasing it and adapting the `range`, typically). Many optimizations are still possible.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more concerned about the worst case scenario of ~10^6 values (this code, translated to C++, also gets me that range), which I need to optimize for.

Comment: Sure, but it seems there is no very smart solution known, see https://oeis.org/A001597

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an algorithm to determine a<sub>k</sub> for a given k.

It works in roughly log(k) time.

1. First I figured out an approach to calculate k for a given a where a<sub>k</sub> < a <  a<sub>k+1</sub>.

The approach is to add in all the values for each power where that number is less than a. Each step adds in trunc(a^1/p) - 1.

Start with the squares, that also adds in all the 4th, 6th, 8th, 10th powers etc. that are also within the range.

Then add in the cubes - that also adds in 6th, 9th, 12th, 15. etc. Note especially that the 6th powers have been added in twice.

We get to the 4ths - and note they have already been added once - so they don't need to be added agan.

power 5 is then added which also adds in 10, 15, 20, etc. Note especially that power 10 has been added in twice from 2 and 5. and power 30 has been added in 3 times.

power 6 - has been added in twice so we need to subtract this number.

and so on.

I created a small program that tells you which powers needed to be added or subtracted through power 80 which should handle k up to a trillion. Here's the result of that program - a 1 next to a power means add in (trunc(a^1/power) - 1) - a negative 1 means to subtract it; a 0 means it neither needs to be added or subtracted.

2 1;
3 1;
4 0;
5 1;
6 -1;
7 1;
8 0;
9 0;
10 -1;
11 1;
12 0;
13 1;
14 -1;
15 -1;
16 0;
17 1;
18 0;
19 1;
20 0;
21 -1;
22 -1;
23 1;
24 0;
25 0;
26 -1;
27 0;
28 0;
29 1;
30 1;
31 1;
32 0;
33 -1;
34 -1;
35 -1;
36 0;
37 1;
38 -1;
39 -1;
40 0;
41 1;
42 1;
43 1;
44 0;
45 0;
46 -1;
47 1;
48 0;
49 0;
50 0;
51 -1;
52 0;
53 1;
54 0;
55 -1;
56 0;
57 -1;
58 -1;
59 1;
60 0;
61 1;
62 -1;
63 0;
64 0;
65 -1;
66 1;
67 1;
68 0;
69 -1;
70 1;
71 1;
72 0;
73 1;
74 -1;
75 0;
76 0;
77 -1;
78 1;
79 1;
80 0;

I coded that up as a small spread sheet and tested it against the OEIS sequence shown within https://oeis.org/A001597 - especially https://oeis.org/A001597/b001597.txt and it seems to work fine.

2. So now that we can calculate k from a, we now go the other way. We can get a first estimate of a<sub>k</sub> from k^2. We plug that back into the formula in 1) above and see how far off k is. We make our new a = (the desired k adjusted by the difference in the formula from 1) ^ 2. Then keep iterating until we find an a that generates the desired k.
3. That a might not be the exact a<sub>k</sub>. It's an a that is somewhere in the range a<sub>k</sub> < a <  a<sub>k+1</sub>.

Probably quickest way to determine the exact a<sub>k</sub> is to take the root of each power - truncate it, then raise it back to the power. The maximum of those values is the a<sub>k</sub> that you desire.

I didn't code up steps 2 and 3 - but the approach above should work. The spreadsheet in step 1 works pretty instantaneously.